# SQL Server Management Studio default query results from "Select top 1000"

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

How do I change the default of `SELECT TOP 1000` query results to go to Text instead of Grid?

Answer (score 0):

In the menu press 'Query', press 'Results To', Press 'Results to Text' or just press CTRL-T

Answer (score 0):

From the Menu:

`Tools -> Options`

then

From the left hand side of the Options window:

`Query Results -> Sql Server`

Then set `"Default destination for results:"` to be `"Results to text"`.

Press `OK`.